# How to transform xml using xsl in android and ios with dart flutter

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, xslt

I have searched on internet to find solution of my problem but I did not find any solution.I want to transform xml using xsl in android or ios with dart.Following code is for transform xml using xsl in java

```
    public String getInvoiceHash(String xmlDocument, Context mContext) throws TransformerException, IOException {
        Transformer transformer = this.getTransformer(mContext);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        StreamResult xmlOutput = new StreamResult(byteArrayOutputStream);
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlDocument)), xmlOutput);

        MessageDigest digest = null;
        byte[] hashSHA256 = null;

        try {
            digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            hashSHA256 = digest.digest(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashSHA256);
        }else{
            return new String(
                    android.util.Base64.encode(hashSHA256, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT),
                    StandardCharsets.UTF_8
            );
        }
    }

    private Transformer getTransformer(Context mContext) throws TransformerConfigurationException {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        InputStream XmlFileInputStream = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.invoice); 
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(XmlFileInputStream));
        transformer.setOutputProperty("encoding", "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("indent", "no");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("omit-xml-declaration", "yes");
        return transformer;
    }
```

I have tried xsltProcessor but it has deprecated.

Comment: did you find something to transform xml using xsl in android or ios ?